# Install Google calendar on Ubuntu 18.04.04

Tags: package-management, dependencies, indicator, calendar

I would like to install a Google calendar indicator on my Ubuntu. I found different tutorial but basically they say the same so I followed and that's what I did.

```
moki@moki-Spectre:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
```

and up to here all good as the result was:

```
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

than I run the `apt update` and it was all good.
finally I tried to install the indicator and here came the problems:

```
moki@moki-Spectre:~$ sudo apt install calendar-indicator
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 calendar-indicator : Depends: gir1.2-handy-0.0 but it is not installable
                      Depends: yaru-theme-gtk but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I solve this? Or maybe you have a better solution to have google calendar visible on my desktop without opening an app?
Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

You may as well consider implementing flathub repository in your system, which allows you to install various software and applications from its sources.

1.) **Add the Flatpak PPA**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak

sudo apt update && sudo apt install flatpak
```

2.) **Install the Flatpak software plugin**:

```
sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak
```

*If you installed the Flatpak software plugin mentioned earlier, then you can install Flatpak apps by searching in the Ubuntu Software center.*

3.) [Install Flatpak and add Nuvola Apps repository](https://nuvola.tiliado.eu/nuvola/ubuntu/bionic/)

or via terminal

`flatpak install nuvola eu.tiliado.NuvolaAppGoogleCalendar`

Comment: How this great answer is connected with *atareao*'s apps?

Comment: Thanks Alexsey, that worked very well! problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

This particular package has no installation candidate for 18.04, as can be inferred from [this issue](https://github.com/atareao/calendar-indicator/issues/2) that was raised on its Github page.

Also on its (Spanish) [website](https://www.atareao.es/aplicacion/calendar-indicator-o-google-calendar-en-ubuntu/) it appears that there is no version that works for 18.04. However, someone ("Antonio Caro") appears to have it working on 18.10 but doesn't tell us how.